# Misunderstood code example

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I was reading this book http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html and I stopped at one of the examples. In my opinion it is incorrect. I think, that there is no undefined behaviour. Am I wrong? Here it is:

> Taking the address of a data object of a type which isn't const and
>   putting it into a pointer to the const-qualified version of the same
>   type is both safe and explicitly permitted; you will be able to use
>   the pointer to inspect the object, but not modify it. Putting the
>   address of a const type into a pointer to the unqualified type is much
>   more dangerous and consequently prohibited (although you can get
>   around this by using a cast). Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
        int i;
        const int ci = 123;

        /* declare a pointer to a const.. */
        const int *cpi;

        /* ordinary pointer to a non-const */
        int *ncpi;

        cpi = &ci;
        ncpi = &i;

        /*
         * this is allowed
         */
        cpi = ncpi;

        /*
         * this needs a cast
         * because it is usually a big mistake,
         * see what it permits below.
         */
        ncpi = (int *)cpi;

        /*
         * now to get undefined behaviour...
         * modify a const through a pointer
         */
        *ncpi = 0;

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

> Example 8.3 
>   As the example shows, it is possible to take the address of a constant object, > generate a pointer
>   to a non-constant, then use the new pointer. This is an error in your
>   program and results in undefined behaviour.

In this example, `ncpi` finally points to `i`, not `ci`. So I think that that makes this example incorrect — there is no undefined behaviour in modifying a non-`const` variable via a pointer. Do you agree?

Comment: Why would you think that modifying a constant is anything other than undefined?

Comment: I don't. Because in this example ncpi finally points to i location, no ci. So I think that that makes this example incorrect. Do you agree?

Comment: Please note that your question would have been answered better without people traipsing down the wrong path if your question suggested "In this example, `ncpi` finally points to `i`, not `ci`. So I think that that makes this example incorrect. Do you agree?"

Comment: I'd suggest emailing the author to clarify what he intended

Answer (score 4):

I agree:  it is a flawed example.  The code itself exhibits defined behavior.

The comment before the final assignment, `*ncpi = 0;`, disagrees with the code.  Probably the author intended to do something different.

---

*My first response was as if the code overwrote a `const`:        I have revised my answer.*

Comment: It is not going to change constant ci value, because at the end ncpi point to i location, not ci. That does not make any sense (I am talking about example in the book saying that).

Comment: @KarolisMilieška:  You are correct.  I *assumed* the code was trying to write to the constant.  Perhaps the author thought it was too and that is why s/he concludes as written.  The comment certainly says the code is meant to write to a `const`.

Comment: @wallyk: You don't have to keep all the original text with a strikethrough. It just degrades the signal-to-noise ratio and doesn't really contribute to the answer. You can go ahead and remove it (though you can keep the comment stating that your first response was misguided; the curious can check the revision history for the answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's undefined because it might be stored in read only memory for example. This won't be the case on x86 systems, but here we have a whole slew of other problems, like aliasing issues if you enable heavy optimizations.

Either way, even just intuitively, why would you think modifying a `const` through a pointer to it that the compiler can't statically validate would be safe?